# Is it better to cache an element in the block/view or the panel?

Tags: drupal, panels

I am creating a panel page that will pull in blocks from a view?  I want to cache these blocks.  So is it better to enable caching of that element in the panel or do it where it was created in the block/view page?  Or does it matter?

FYI, There are other areas of the page that are too dynamic for me to cache the entire page using other methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the top level, to get the cached version faster. In this case, that would be the panel page.

That would also cache the entire pane, instead of just caching the content of it, be it a block, a view or something else.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a panel, containing a block display of a view, you're doing it wrong (probably).  You should be using a content-pane display of your view for use in the panel.

That said, only the outer-most cache is used, so if you cache the panel, and cache the block inside the panel, and cache the view inside the block, only the panels-cache is actually used.